Best practices for setting up a test suite for a python library?
note: here library means a package that is installed from some wheel/egg/tar file. as opposed to a regular package which is just a container of modules basically. package usually is used for both as far as I know.
So I'm working on writing a library in python that I will put into a package registry. For me its a private registry, but for generality it could just as well be PyPi.
While getting started on the tests for it I realized that this is a different use case than what I'm used to. Usually i just make code and then scp it somewhere not as a proper library.
So the first question would be should my tests be run on the built library which is installed in a different environment, or should they be run on the source code before the package is built? I think that possibly it could do both by changing some options to pytest for now. however as the code base and tests grow it could become more challenging to ensure that the imports will work correctly for both of the use cases. Given that observation I'm leaning towards having the default be that tests should be run on the built package.
I can conceive of various ways of supporting both but it kind of just seems like unnecessary complexity at the moment.
To try and make this less subjective I'll ask this. In the average case of software development are test suites typically run on a installed version of the software or on the source code its self? Additionally, in general does python follow this trend?

You can use the Tox tool to automatically create a venv, build your package, install it and its dependencies into the venv, and then run your test commands. This also helps for testing with different Python versions. But personally, Tox hasn't helped me find any packaging-related bugs (when using a modern venv-based package manager, not just vanilla Pip).

I think this question is not necessarily restricted to Python or the tools you mentioned - it is always the same situation whenever you develop software in an environment which differs from the targeted  production environment, with a packaging & release process in between. Hence, I will try to answer this in a language-agnostic way.

are test suites typically run on a installed version of the software or on the source code its self? Additionally, in general does python follow this trend?

This is not a question of "trend" or popularity. It is a question of practical matters, of the trade-off between "ease-of-work" vs. the risk of getting "false positive or false negative reports" from the test suite.
On one hand, the cycle of "testing / debugging / changing code / rerun the tests again" should be as quick, as short and as painless as possible. That's best achieved when your tests can be executed directly for a debuggable version of your code, immediately after you changed something in the code, and when the test suit runs only a few seconds. When a test fails, it is great when you can advise your IDE to stop the execution with a break point at the failed assertion, and show the code including it's whole stack frame in the debugger.
On the other hand, the process of compiling / packaging a program into a deployable component itself, or altering the program's runtime environment may introduce errors which are not showing up in the unpackaged debug version of your program. Hence, having tests in place for that case is also a good idea.
As with any trade-off, there is no all-or-nothing recipe for dealing with this situation. Whether your test process works best with an unpackaged or packaged variant of a library depends heavily on

the kind of software (and the kind of tests) you are developing,
how different the development and production environments are,
how long the packaging process takes,
how quick the test suit runs,
how much increased effort will be generated by maintaining tests which work in both environments, and
how cumbersome it is to debug a packaged version in comparison to an unpackaged version.

As a general strategy, you may consider to split your tests into two (not necessarily disjoint) categories:

tests which are mainly run in the debug environment, and where you are quite confident that if they don't fail there, they won't fail in a production-like environment as well. Unit tests fall typically under this category, but not necessarily exclusively, you can have also integration tests, end-to-end tests, categorization tests there, as long as they don't take more than a minute to run.

tests which you run in the production-like test environment (hence on a packaged version). This may be time-consuming tests, or tests for the package integrity. If you are using a CI (continuous integration) process, you may place these tests on the CI server, and let the packaging and execution of the test suit happen there (for example, as part of a nightly or hourly build, whatever you do in your environment). On the server it will usually not matter if the test suite requires an hour or more to complete. But even if you do not use a CI server, you can run these tests, for example, shortly before you create a new release of your library (but not during normal, daily development work).


Still, it is a good idea to design all tests, including the tests for the production-like environment in a way you can run them in your development & debug environment as well, since it makes it a lot easier to find the root cause of a failing test. That does not mean you will run all of them daily. But, for example, in case the CI server has reported a failure during the last nightly build, you probably want to debug the failing test in your dev environment.

I meant trend in the statistical sense. Like does python do it how it is handled in other languages and environments. Anyways this is very good information and just what I was looking for. Thank you!

@gnarlyninja: even if I had some  some stats for this topic, I don't think they would tell you what makes most sense for your specific case ;-)
